# SignalR connection closed while refreshing the page

Tags: signalr

Im using SignalR for real time notification. My problem is that, after initiating connection to the server HUB, the connection gets disconnected if I refresh the page. Can anybody give me an idea why the connection gets disconnected on every page refreshes.

```
public class TaskHub : Hub 
{
   public void AddSession(string sessionId) 
   {
       Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, sessionId); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: can you share your signalr hub code? i can help  you.

Comment: public class TaskHub : Hub  
    {  
        public void AddSession(string sessionId)   
        {  
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, sessionId);  
        }  
    }

Comment: @SerdarÇatalpınar this AddSession method initiates connection.

Comment: SignalR closes the connection when you leave the page. Then the page is loaded and SignalR is creating a new connection. When it reloads how it would know how to reconnect? All the state (and if you are using websockets - the websocket connection) is lost when you reload a page.

Answer (score 1):

> DI container  : Hub must work singleton

```
builder.RegisterType<FeedHub>().ExternallyOwned().SingleInstance();
```

You manage OnReconnected event in hub.

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
      ...
      return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnReconnected()
{
     ...
     return base.OnReconnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
     ....
     return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}
```

Comment: I have a question serdar, When will be my client side onDisconnect() method called?

Comment: if you dont  call , it does not work. $.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {  alert("We are disconnected!"); 
});

Comment: is it possible that onDisconnect() method automatically called by signalr for every page reload?

Comment: No. I am using signalr hub for feed. OnReconnected method work when  page refresh. you can debug. Hub must work singleton.